# Changing from Linux to Windows scripting Curl

Tags: linux, batch-file, curl

I need to run a command to request new certs from our CA. We have over 1000 devices so I would be running this in a batch script

In Linux the command

```
curl --connect-timeout 30 --max-time 60 -sk https://ssl.wsgc.com/vedsdk/Certificates/Retrieve -X POST -d @cert-retrieve-labtesttop.wsgc.com.json -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Bearer <Redacted>'
```

But when I run that in windows I get the error "{"Error":"Content-type not supported."}"

In truth I would love to be able to run this as a text file instead of JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows is weird about single quotes, so all of the single quotes in your command need to be replaced with double quotes.

```
curl --connect-timeout 30 --max-time 60 -sk https://ssl.wsgc.com/vedsdk/Certificates/Retrieve -X POST -d @cert-retrieve-labtesttop.wsgc.com.json -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer <Redacted>"
```

Additionally, if you had had any instance of double quotes already in your command, those would have needed to be replaced with escaped quotes, like `\"`.

Comment: So your saying it should be something like this ?

curl --connect-timeout 30 --max-time 60 -sk https://ssl.wsgc.com/vedsdk/Certificates/Request -X POST -d @labtesttop.wsgc.com-request.json -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer <Redacted>"

When i tried that I got  "{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"The request is missing a required parameter or is otherwise malformed"}"

Comment: @DanielPierce - Then there's likely something else in your Authorization Bearer token that needs to be escaped that I can't help you with since you've redacted it. But the correct answer to the code that you posted is to use double quotes.

Comment: But the error says nothing about the  Authorization Bearer. In the first error it talked about the Content-type not supported. But when I did the double quotes as you suggested it says 


"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"The request is missing a required parameter or is otherwise malformed"}" 

So i can only assume that the issue is still with the Content-type 

I admit that I am still learning but unless you can show me where you got that the issue is now with the  Authorization Bearer I am sorry but I do not understand the logic there

Comment: If your code worked in Linux and it doesn't work in Windows, and I fixed every single problem that I could find to make it work in Windows, then it stands to reason that the remaining issues are in the parts that I can't see. The only thing that you haven't shown me is the Authorization token, which I can only assume has some character like a `&` that you'd need to escape. If the problem was still with Content-Type, the error would say so.

Comment: So if the token was something like +cS+TKKQGSniMb7inb+Q4A==

What would need to be escaped?

Comment: I'm not seeing anything obvious in there, but I also have no way to test anything. _Maybe_ the `=`s, but I didn't need to escape them when I tried to send them as a string to a webhook. When I'm googling the error messages that you're getting (which is what _you_ should be doing), I'm seeing a lot of people recommend using `-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` instead. But again, I have no way of testing this.

Comment: OK so I have got this part working and I am assuming I need to post another question for the next part. But I can not create and download the cert from the CA. But it comes down in what appears to be a Base64 format File ends in .B64. But all attempts ad decoding that have failed 

The Linux script states 

# extract the combined cert from it base64 file
jq .CertificateData $CERT_NAME.b64 | sed -es/\"//g | base64 --decode > $CERT_NAME.out"

maybe I am missing something